# How could you use one object to update another while the code is running in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

I'm writing an ATM program in class and one method I need to create is a transaction function where funds are deducted from one account and added to another. The bank accounts only exist while the code is run.

This is the constructor:

```
def __init__(self, AccName, AccPin, AccBalance):
        self.AccName = AccName
        self.AccDateCreated = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S %d/%m/%Y")
        self.AccPin = AccPin
        self.AccBalance = AccBalance
        self.AccWrongPin = 0
```

and these are an example of two instances:

```
Flan0712 = ATMs.BankATM('Flying Dutchman', '0543', 5450.79)
Geel0712 = ATMs.BankATM('George Russel', '8967', 789.67)
```

How would I create a method that can access another account and update both balances?

Comment: Create a method which can take another object as one of its parameters? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Genuinely stuck at the beginning. Thank you for the suggestion, I'll try it now!

Answer (score 0):

I am really new at this, so sorry if this is not the most efficient new response, but be easy on me I need to start somewhere.

I put this together on your above info, what are you trying to do after creating the class?

```
import time

class Machine:  
    def __init__(self, AccName, AccPin, AccBalance):
        self.AccName = AccName
        self.AccDateCreated = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S %d/%m/%Y")
        self.AccPin = AccPin
        self.AccBalance = AccBalance
        self.AccWrongPin = 0 


Flan0712 = Machine('Flying Dutchman', '0543', 5450.79)
Geel0712 = Machine('George Russel', '8967', 789.67)

print('\n')
print("-------------")
print("Account 1")
print(Flan0712.AccName)
print(Flan0712.AccPin)
print(Flan0712.AccDateCreated)
print(Flan0712.AccBalance)
print("-------------")
print("Account 2")
print(Geel0712.AccName)
print(Geel0712.AccPin)
print(Geel0712.AccDateCreated)
print(Geel0712.AccBalance)
print("-------------")
```

Let me know what you are trying to do after! I will try to add more.

Thank you!

Comment: After this is want to create a method within the class that can deduct funds from Flan0712 and add them to Geel0712 while the code is still running, I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can think along these lines:
Create a method like

```
def update(self, other, amount):
  # Fill this
```

where `self` and `other` are two account objects. You can access the `self.AccBalance` and `other.AccBalance` to debit one and credit another. Or preferably, create methods like:

```
def debit(self, amount):
  # Fill this
```

and

```
def credit(self, amount):
  # Fill this
```

to do the job.

Comment: Would I put the above, inside the Class 'Machine', I made? I am trying to learnt this too, lol

Comment: I think this may be the best method but I just wanted to keep all the processes in one class, thank you for the help!!

Comment: You should define these in the class itself as instance methods. Also the class may be renamed from `Machine` to `Account`.